# How to filter an array from all elements of another array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I get the data from API like this.

```
data1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Ant'},
    {id:2, name:'Bird'},
    {id:4, name:'Dog'},
    {id:5, name:'Egg'}
];

data2 = [
    {id:2, name:'Bird'},
    {id:3, name:'Cat'},
    {id:4, name:'Dog'},
    {id:6, name:'Fish'}
];
```

and I coding to get the data of 2 arrays by using filter and map array but I don't know how to filter 'data 2' in 'data 1' to get the result (check id if it's the same won't show in the result)

My expect result is

```
result = [
    {id:1, name:'Ant'},
    {id:3, name:'Cat'},
    {id:5, name:'Egg'},
    {id:6, name:'Fish'}
];
```

This is my code.

```
let getExistdata = {...this.props.data1.data}

let getExistedDataId = this.props.animal.data.map((existData)=> {
  let animalList= this.props.data2.data.filter(animal=> (animal.id !== this.props.id) && (animal.id !== existData.id) );
  console.log(animalList);

  return animalList;

});
```

Thank you

Comment: What is the condition for filtering. You do need to mention that and post some code that you tried

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri I just edit content. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

One way is to `filter` both arrays and `concat` them together:

```js
data1 = [
    {id:1, name:'Ant'},
    {id:2, name:'Bird'},
];

data2 = [
    {id:2, name:'Bird'},
    {id:3, name:'Cat'}
];

const filterBird = (data) => data.id !== 2;

const filtered1 = data1.filter(filterBird);
const filtered2 = data2.filter(filterBird)

const output = filtered1.concat(filtered2);

alert(JSON.stringify(output));
```